# Browsers gets messed across dual monitor in portrait setup

Tags: windows-7, firefox, multiple-monitors, browser, internet-explorer

I have recently changed my dual monitor setup from landscape to portrait. The desktop is extended and not duplicated.

I'm having a problem viewing websites when the browser spans across two monitors. All applications work just fine, but for some reason browsers (**Firefox/IE**) duplicate when they span across monitors.

Screenshot 1: Browser not spanning monitors, no problems:

[image]

Screenshot 2: Browser spanning monitors, weird problems:

[image]

Whet you see in *Screenshot 2* is not two browsers but only one. The same one that was in *Screenshot 1*, it has only been move to so some of it is on monitor 2.

Here is the really weird thing. As you can see in *Screenshot 2* I have marked with arrows **Questions**, **Tags** & **Users**. If I were to point the mouse over the **Questions** arrows and click, I would be clicking on Questions button of Superuser. The browser window is duplicated only visually but I can still interact with it as if it were extended. Same thing for the close button (red X) in the upper right of monitor one, clicking on it will do nothing because it is only visually duplicated.

**Notes**

- This problem did not exist in when I had the monitors in landscape.
- I've tried Firefox and Internet Explorer, both have the same problem.
- I also tried the browser in **Eclipse**, it did not have this problem.

Comment: [Monitor setup](http://sv.tinypic.com/r/o6z37l/8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

In your browser, disable **Hardware Acceleration**.